# DLL в C++ (вопросы)

Tags: c++, dll, msdn

**Вопросы**

1. Когда я загружаю DLL в память с помощью функции ***LoadLibrary()*** будет ли она заново загружаться при очередном вызове этой функции, учитывая, что я еще не выгружал эту DLL? Или мне нужно самому написать данный механизм?
2. Я так и не понял что это значит:

> Система поддерживает количество ссылок на каждый процесс для всех загруженных модулей. Вызов LoadLibrary увеличивает количество ссылок. Вызов функции FreeLibrary или FreeLibraryAndExitThread уменьшает количество ссылок. Система выгружает модуль, когда его число ссылок достигает нуля или когда процесс завершается (независимо от количества ссылок).

Не могли бы вы объяснить, что **Microsoft** хотели этим сказать? (источник MSDN: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibrarya)

Comment: Процесс запросил, операционка загрузила в память DLL, сказала "раз!". Пришел b запросил второй процесс. Операционка: "так, смотрим... ага, он уже в памяти, грузить ничего не надо. Два!" Прошел запрос на освобождение — "сколько у нас? Два? Минус один, остается 1. Не ноль? Не ноль. Значит, ею пользуются, значит, выгружать из памяти пока не надо"... Так понятнее?

Comment: @Harry, Можно как скороговорку прочитать)). Спасибо